# Как реализовать динамичную смену языка? JavaFX

Tags: javafx

Хочу реализовать адекватное переключение языков в приложении, чтобы сразу после нажатие кнопки "сменить язык" все компоненты автоматически поменяли название.
Пока что сделал так:

```
public  void setEnglish(ActionEvent actionEvent) {

    Main.locale = new Locale("en");
    rb = ResourceBundle.getBundle("ua.javaFX.myprograms.address_book.bundles.Locale", Main.locale);

    mainStage.setTitle(rb.getString("key.address_book"));
    btnAdd.setText(rb.getString("key.add"));
    btnEdit.setText(rb.getString("key.change"));
    btnDelete.setText(rb.getString("key.delete"));
    btnSearch.setText(rb.getString("key.search"));
    btnLanguage.setText(rb.getString("key.language"));
    btnEnglish.setText(rb.getString("key.english"));
    btnRussian.setText(rb.getString("key.russian"));
}
```

Суть вопроса: есть какой-то цивилизованный способ для обновления содержания страницы?
Если я не ошибаюсь, в SWING таким является:

```
SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(frame);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для того, чтобы вам сделать такое, необходимо использовать [bindings](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/binding/jfxpub-binding.htm).

Вам нужна resources factory :

```
public class ObservableResourceFactory {

    private ObjectProperty<ResourceBundle> resources = new SimpleObjectProperty<>();
    public ObjectProperty<ResourceBundle> resourcesProperty() {
        return resources ;
    }
    public final ResourceBundle getResources() {
        return resourcesProperty().get();
    }
    public final void setResources(ResourceBundle resources) {
        resourcesProperty().set(resources);
    }

    public StringBinding getStringBinding(String key) {
        return new StringBinding() {
            { bind(resourcesProperty()); }
            @Override
            public String computeValue() {
                return getResources().getString(key);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Далее, в своем коде можете написать такое

```
ObservableResourceFactory resourceFactory = .... ;

resourceBundle.setResources(...);

Label greetingLabel = new Label();
greetingLabel.textProperty().bind(resourceFactory.getStringBinding("greeting"));
```

И в любой момент, когда вы будет обновлять ресурсы

```
resourceFactory.setResources(...);
```

на лейбле текст будет меняться.

Вот пример, как это работает

```
import java.util.ListResourceBundle;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.binding.StringBinding;
import javafx.beans.property.ObjectProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleObjectProperty;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.ListCell;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ResourceBundleBindingExample extends Application {

    private static final String RESOURCE_NAME = Resources.class.getTypeName() ;

    private static final ObservableResourceFactory RESOURCE_FACTORY = new ObservableResourceFactory();

    static {
        RESOURCE_FACTORY.setResources(ResourceBundle.getBundle(RESOURCE_NAME));
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        ComboBox<Locale> languageSelect = new ComboBox<>();
        languageSelect.getItems().addAll(Locale.ENGLISH, Locale.FRENCH);
        languageSelect.setValue(Locale.ENGLISH);
        languageSelect.setCellFactory(lv -> new LocaleCell());
        languageSelect.setButtonCell(new LocaleCell());

        languageSelect.valueProperty().addListener((obs, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            if (newValue != null) {
                RESOURCE_FACTORY.setResources(ResourceBundle.getBundle(RESOURCE_NAME, newValue));
            }
        });

        Label label = new Label();
        label.textProperty().bind(RESOURCE_FACTORY.getStringBinding("greeting"));

        BorderPane root = new BorderPane(null, languageSelect, null, label, null);
        root.setPadding(new Insets(10));
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 400);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static class LocaleCell extends ListCell<Locale> {
        @Override
        public void updateItem(Locale locale, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(locale, empty);
            if (empty) {
                setText(null);
            } else {
                setText(locale.getDisplayLanguage(locale));
            }
        }
    }

    public static class ObservableResourceFactory {

        private ObjectProperty<ResourceBundle> resources = new SimpleObjectProperty<>();
        public ObjectProperty<ResourceBundle> resourcesProperty() {
            return resources ;
        }
        public final ResourceBundle getResources() {
            return resourcesProperty().get();
        }
        public final void setResources(ResourceBundle resources) {
            resourcesProperty().set(resources);
        }

        public StringBinding getStringBinding(String key) {
            return new StringBinding() {
                { bind(resourcesProperty()); }
                @Override
                public String computeValue() {
                    return getResources().getString(key);
                }
            };
        }

    }

    public static class Resources extends ListResourceBundle {

        @Override
        protected Object[][] getContents() {
            return new Object[][] {
                    {"greeting", "Hello"}
            };
        }

    }

    public static class Resources_fr extends ListResourceBundle {

        @Override
        protected Object[][] getContents() {
            return new Object[][] {
                    {"greeting", "Bonjour"}
            };
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

P.S. ответ взят с [английского SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32464974/javafx-change-application-language-on-the-run).